# Error while loading java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run an application in Android Studio on a physical device API 16. I am using a server made in Node.js . Through a get method my data should be retrieved and displayed, in exchange nothing is shown and I have the following error:

```
E/Manager: Error while loading the events
       java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTimeoutBase$TimeoutSubscriber.onTimeout(OperatorTimeoutBase.java:178)
           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTimeout$1$1.call(OperatorTimeout.java:43)
           at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:187)
           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:150)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:264)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Is it possible that my PC's memory can't handle to do the task(4GB RAM)?

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't find out exactly why this error occurs. By connecting (both my laptop and my device) to another WiFi network than the one I tried the first time it worked like a charm. To test it out, I tried with a third WiFi network on a different location and it didn't work again. So it seems like this issue has to do with the network you are connected to. Hope it helps someone :D